# Neo4j Certificate Chain

Tags: neo4j, ssl-certificate

I am trying to set up a neo4j server with a set of certificates for https. I have the key used to get the certs, the certificate itself, and the ca certificate chain file. According to the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-https):

> Neo4j also supports chained SSL certificates. This requires to have all certificates in PEM format combined in one file and the private key needs to be in DER format.

I've encoded my key in DER format and have that set up, however I am having trouble getting the certificate chain set up correctly. I combined all the certificates in one file (PEM) and gave it to neo4j, and it crashed silently trying to start the server. On the off hand, I took the first certificate and changed it to DER, changed neo4j to use that, and it started but browsers/curl throw a fit because there's no CA chain along with it.

This is using neo4j 2.2.0 community edition.

Any suggestions as to how to get neo4j to use PEM certificate chains correctly?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.2/community/server/src/test/resources/certificates for certifcates used when running the unit tests of Neo4j. Most interesting test case is https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2/community/server/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/security/ssl/KeyStoreFactoryTest.java#L82

Double check if your pem file has the same structure than the one provided there.